# Angular Directives - How do I restore Angular's special character rendering after modifying inner HTML attributes?

Tags: html, angular, string, special-characters

I have the following Directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[Foo]'
})
export class Foo implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        element.title = element.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

If I apply this directive to a div that dynamically fetches data from a field in the component, then set this field to be the string "<" I get "%gt;" instead of "<" in the UI.

I highly suspect this is because I 'get' the pre-rendered text from the HTML element, and it includes a sanitizing mechanism that converts "<" instead of "%gt;".

Assuming I have to use directives and can not specify the title field manually, how can I fix the problem without making inelegant "find and replace"es for all the special characters that are escaped?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I think you have to use something called DomSanitizer https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer,

Also refer to, https://angular.io/guide/security#trusting-safe-values

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[Foo]'
})
export class Foo implements AfterViewInit {
    constructor(
      private elementRef: ElementRef,
      private sanitizer: DomSanitizer
    ) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        const element = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
        element.title = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(element.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Comment: bypassSecurityTrustHtml is an alarming method name... are there any security concerns involved?